# Factory Pattern with a Singleton

Tags: design-patterns

Say I have an array of items that I load into an items manager on application startup and each of these items belongs to some group, say were modeling animals and I wish to attain the animal type. Once I've created these objects and loaded them into memory could I used some form of a factory pattern that when passed a given string e.g. "bird" could randomly pick a bird type animal from the file manager. Would this still conform to the Factory Pattern since it's not strictly creating an object? and if not are there any design patterns that can decouple requesting specific objects?

Comment: Sounds closer to a FlyWeight pattern

Comment: Please provide a sample code to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement resembles the need of FlyWeight pattern rather than Factory with Singleton.

> A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory usage by sharing as
>   much data as possible with other similar object.

For more details you can refer [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) or [OODesign](https://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html)